# Ag grid table react how can we download all data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using `Ag grid` that has this function

```js
const onBtnExport = useCallback(() => {
  gridRef.current.api.exportDataAsCsv();
}, []);
```

but the problem is it only downloads current page data but I want to download all data. if we have 3 pages, all data should be downloadable in one click. how can we do this using `ag grid` table in React? I am using the above function.

Comment: Can you add to the question the code with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?